# AutoMapper mapping two models to one viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper, automapper-9

I have two models and one view model.

Model:

```cs
public User
{
    public string UserName {  get; set; }
    public int RoleId {  get; set; }
}

public Role
{
    public int RoleId {  get; set; }
    public string Name {  get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public UserIndex
{
    public string UserName {  get; set; }
    public string RoleName {  get; set; }
}
```

I tried to add config:

```cs
public class Role_User_UserIndex : Profile
{
    public Role_User_UserIndex()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserIndex>();
        CreateMap<Role, UserIndex>()
            .ForMember(des => des.RoleName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
        CreateMap<UserIndex, UserIndex>()
            .ForMember(des => des.RoleName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RoleName))
            .ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((source, destination, member) => member != null));
    }
}
```

and controller:

```
        var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperConfig.Role_User_UserIndex>()).CreateMapper();
        var roles = db.Roles;
        var users = db.Users;
         
        var viewMode1 = mapper.Map<List<UserIndex>>(users);
        var viewMode2 = mapper.Map<List<UserIndex>>(roles);
        var indexViewModel= mapper.Map(viewModel, viewMode2);
```

The viewMode1 has 10 users, and the viewMode2 has 3 roles.

However, the merged result indexViewModel has 10 rows data, but the RoleName is null.

If I swap viewModel with viewMode2, indexViewModel has 3 rows data and UserName is null.

I also tried to remove ".ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((source, destination, member) => member != null));" , but still not working.

How can I map `RoleName` to `indexViewModel`?

My AutoMapper version is `9.0.0`.

Thanks!

Comment: You need `ProjectTo` instead of `Map`. Check http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html and https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Sorry... I don’t get it, because my class don't have subclass, I try to use this code but not working:
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<User, UserIndex>();
                cfg.CreateMap<Role, UserIndex>().ForMember(des => des.RoleName, c => c.MapFrom(r => r.Name));
            }).CreateMapper();

            var destination = config.ProjectTo<UserIndex>(users).ToList();
            destination = config.ProjectTo<UserIndex>(roles).ToList();

Comment: You'll have to add FK class properties.